# node js - use key generated by a SmartCard HSM with NodeRSA module

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#11

I'm using the module [pkcs11js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkcs11js) to generate RSA keys with a smart card HSM as shown [here in the Example #3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkcs11js#example-3).

```
var publicKeyTemplate = [
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN, value: false },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL, value: "My RSA Public Key" },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, value: new Buffer([1, 0, 1]) },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_MODULUS_BITS, value: 2048 },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_VERIFY, value: true }
];
var privateKeyTemplate = [
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN, value: false },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL, value: "My RSA Private Key" },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_SIGN, value: true },
];
var keys = pkcs11.C_GenerateKeyPair(session, { mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN }, publicKeyTemplate, privateKeyTemplate);
```

If I print `keys`, I get something like:

```
{ privateKey: <Buffer 70 97 f7 03 00 00 00 00>,
publicKey: <Buffer b0 ea f2 03 00 00 00 00> }
```

Now I want to encrypt/decrypt with [NodeRSA module](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa), but don't know how to create the key object (with `new NodeRSA(...)`) that is used to encrypt/decrypt, from this key pair previously generated.

It's not required the use of NodeRSA, I just need a way to encrypt/decrypt in Node JS using a key pair from the smart card, in case someone has an example of how to do this with another library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some attributes have a default value for PKCS#11. For the private key this means that `CKA_PRIVATE` is set. This means that the value of the private exponent (and the CRT parameters) are not accessible; the idea was to protect them using the smart card, right?

Usually you cannot retrieve the RSA private key parameters (except the modulus) from a smart card *even* if you set the right attribute values. So private key operations cannot be performed using a **software only** implementation such as NodeRSA, simply because the required values are unavailable. You'll have to perform them using the smart card, e.g. by using **example 7** of pkcs11js.

---

Ok, so that's it for the private key, let's take a look at public key operations. As you may have guessed you can normally retrieve the attributes of the public key. For public key operations you require the modulus and the public exponent. Those can be retrieved using `C_GetAttributeValue`. For this you require the object handle which can be found using `C_FindObjects` (or you can use the handle retrieved when generating the key pair, obviously).

After retrieving the attribute values you can construct a public key from them and use them in a software implementation. It depends on the smart card and PKCS#11 library implementation if you can also perform the operations directly on the smart card.

---

What you are currently seeing when printing the `keys` are the (session dependent) object handles of the public and private key. Those are usually completely independent from the attributes (the value) of the public and private key.

Comment: Thanks, I'm retrieving the modulus and public exponent with `C_GetAttributeValue` as you suggested, do you know how to construct the public key or how to encrypt with the public key on the smart card using this library? Example 7 is for signing/verifying, I tried [example 8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkcs11js#example-8) -changing the second argument- but I get: `Error: CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED`, though I know the smart card supports RSA encryption/decription, so it's something I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @myrmix The PKCS#11 library also has to support it. Often smart cards are only supporting *decryption* with the private key (there is little use for encrypting with the public key on card). As for constructing the public key, a quick search shows `http://nullege.com/codes/search/M2Crypto.RSA.new_pub_key` from M2Crypto, there are probably others.